# Unable to copy files from protected folders

Tags: windows-7, permissions, batch, file-permissions, batch-file

When I try to run the following

```
copy %HOMEPATH%\"My Documents"\test.txt %CD%
```

from c:\backupSettings

I get the error:

> Access is denied.
>           0 file(s) copied.

Comment: Try running from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: I tried that and the visual studio command prompt run as administrator. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Just so you know, when using command-line file utilities you can reference the current directory with `.` instead of using `%CD%`. So `copy C:\Folder\*.* .` copies all files from the directory 'Folder' to the current directory.  Also, `..` always represents the parent of the current directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is the command:

```
copy %HOMEPATH%\"My Documents"\test.txt %CD%
```

It should be:

```
copy %HOMEPATH%\Documents\test.txt %CD%
```

Since Windows Vista the documents folder was renamed. Windows 7 introduced some weird feature that shows it as "My Documents", but the underlying path (which you must use from the command line) is "Documents".

Actually, it gets even more confusing. Vista put a symbolic link called "My Documents" in the profile folder, so legacy applications would still work. Access is denied under normal circumstances, and it should *not* be used, touched, modified, etc. Windows 7 keeps that symbolic link, but also shows the "Documents" folder as "My Documents". If you show hidden/system filed, you'll actually see two "My Documents" folders in your profile in Windows 7 - one is a mask put on the "Documents" folder while the other is the symbolic link. The symbolic link is the one you're actually trying to navigate to when you go to the path `%HOMEPATH%\My Documents\`, and of course that is forbidden.

Also, I don't think you can put quotes in the middle of a path. You should put them around the whole path, e.g.:

```
copy "%HOMEPATH%\Documents\test.txt" "%CD%"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take owenership of the folder, u[sing this script](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/). See if you have any errors after doing that.

Comment: this looks useful, but I can't go around running this script on random machines.

Comment: @Kaizen thought it was a problem with permissions, dumb me ;p

Comment: it is a good script, but it is good practice to avoid side effects.